# NodeJS - Chained HTTP promises are not being fired for hosts in /etc/hosts

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, promise

I'm building an electron application and am using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module from npm (and request-promise for the promises).
The problem occurs when I try to chain 2 promises one after another

```
 return request(`${SERVER_ADDRESS}/invite/${key}`)
            .then((fHost) => {
            return request(`http://${fHost}:9000/api/start/${key}`)
        })
        .then(json => {
               console.log("reached");
        }).catch((e) => { console.log(e) });
```

Only the first HTTP request is being fired, not the second one.
If I try to fire the same routine again, the second HTTP request is also being fired.

I must mention that both of these hosts that I'm requesting have a mapping in `/etc/hosts` to `127.0.0.1`, and in case I replace the name of the server with `localhost`, the requests are being fired correctly in their order.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: According to my knowledge, you can't do `then` with the `request` module mentioned. You'll have to promisify the module. Or use promised version of it.

Comment: I have used the "request-promise" module, just didn't think it's important to mention it.. I edited it to make it more clear

Comment: In the case when only first request is fired, does it fall into the `catch` block and log something?

Comment: No, no error is shown..

Comment: Just to test, have you tried using any other random URLs to make sure it has something to do with `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Yes, and I mentioned it... if I use `localhost` it works

Comment: After updating `/etc/hosts`, the effect is usually immediately. But on the safe side you can restart your network service to double check.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/665995/after-modifying-etc-hosts-which-service-is-needed-to-be-restarted-in-ubuntu